# Find&Replace script in Google Docs SpreadSheets

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have google spreadsheet with direct links to images (jpg and png):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoPGWppcjtzhdDh6MW1QNVJhSHlwVTlfRnRtd0pvNGc&usp=sharing

I want to increase rows heights starting from "2nd row" to 100px and render images there.

It's possible to do via Find&Replace:

1. Find `jpg` and Replace to `jpg", 1)`
2. Find `http://img` and Replace to `=image("http://img)`
3. Select rows and Scale them

and the same for png image-urls.

Watch this screencast http://www.screenr.com/S0RH

Is it possible to automate it via script? I think - YES! It have to be pretty simple but I googled a lot but haven't found the solution. I can't do it myself as don't know coding. Will anyone help and make this script?

Answer (score 0):

A function to do what you ask is simple, if you have a basic understanding of the language (Javascript), know how to use the development environment, and read the API documentation.

For example, see this script. It's been added to your shared spreadsheet, so you can also view it (and run it) in the script editor there.

```
/**
 * Scan column A, looking for images that have been inserted using
 * =image() function. For any row with an image, set the row height
 * to 100 pixels.
 */
function resizeImageRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // Get a handle on the sheet
  var HEADERS = 1;                              // Number of header rows at top
  var firstRow = HEADERS + 1;                   // First row with data
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();             // Last row with data
  var imageRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1);  // Column A

  // Get all formulas from Column A, without Headers
  var formulas = imageRange.getFormulas().slice(HEADERS);

  // Look for image() formulas, and set the row height.
  for (var i = 0; i< formulas.length; i++) {
    if (formulas[i][0].indexOf('image') !== -1) {
      sheet.setRowHeight(i+firstRow, 100); // Set height to 100 pixels
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do this with the find and replace function under the edit menu, just make sure you click "search in formulas" and it will find and replace in the formula.